# Have trouble when import and develop Magento project in Eclipse

Tags: php, magento

I have some trouble when first time develop with Magento. I download and install all the magento sample data and source code from `magentocommerce.com/download`, I put it in `htdocs/magento` folder of XAMPP directory, everything is fine and I can start it by enter this link `localhost/magento`

- Magento source code location: i.stack.imgur.com/31lcK.png
- Magento screen from source code: i.stack.imgur.com/jGYyB.png

So I want to import that source code to Eclipse for futher development, so I create an empty PHP Project in Eclipse, name it `mymagento`, put it in the same `htdocs` folder on XAMPP. Then I import all file from `magento` into `mymagento`, it looks normal. I'm now having exact folder with the `magento` source code.

- Import all file from magento to mymagento project: i.stack.imgur.com/QGDjj.png
- mymagento project structure: i.stack.imgur.com/TJzJE.jpg

First problem is when I start `mymagento` project by type `localhost/mymagento`, the browser auto redirect to `localhost/magento`, I don't understand? If I remove `magento` folder, my `mymagento` project could not start.

Second problem is I can't not add or change anything in `mymagento` site until I copy all changes to `magento` folder. For example, if I add new module configuration file like `demo.xml` in `mymagento/app/etc/modules`, the new module will not appear in "Disable Modules Output" in Admin Panel until I copy that config file to `magento/app/etc/modules`. So I don't think `mymagento` project are working properly. In brief, how can I import all `magento` project into Eclipse for extend and develop more?

Sorry if my English isn't well.

Comment: did you check your base url in **core_config_data** table in db?

Comment: It is 127.0.0.1/magento/. So this is a reason for the first problem?

Comment: @JaydeepPandya I modified it to `127.0.0.1/mymagento/` and now the browser said "The page isn't redirecting properly".

Comment: Remove all directories under `mymagento/var/cache` to clear the magento cache.

Comment: @tino.codes I did, and now the browser give me blank page.